# How type value in AutoNumeric input with set vMin

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an issue with Autonumeric plugin:

**Html**

```
<input id="testInput" type="text" value="" />
```

**Javascript**

```
//Init Autonumeric
$("#testInput").autoNumeric('init', {
  aSep: '.',
  aDec: ',',
  aForm: true,
  vMax: '999999999',
  vMin: '20.00'
});
```

I try to type in testInput, but I don't success because `vMin` is `20.00`.

Example: http://fiddle.jshell.net/gatfil/7h604exp/1/

Autonumeric http://www.decorplanit.com/plugin/

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [`Autonumeric` plugin documentation:](http://www.decorplanit.com/plugin/)

> If the minimum / maximum values are both positive or negative you MUST have a default value assigned to the field that is greater than or equal to the minimum value and less than or equal to the maximum value.
>
> **IMPORTANT** - please understand that vMin & vMax settings are limits.
>   Meaning the user cannot enter a value greater than the vMax value and
>   cannot enter or delete a value below the vMin setting. When setting
>   the vMin & vMax values to both positive or negative you could create a
>   paradoxical situation which limits the user ability to enter values.
>   Consider the following:
>
> ...
>
> vMin:'10' & vMax:'100' and no default value - you can never
>   enter any value.

So *If the minimum / maximum values are both positive or negative you MUST have a **default value assigned** to the field* and you're in the sample situation *vMin:'10' & vMax:'100' and no default value - you can never enter any value.*

So the solution is to set the `vMin` value as default value for you input:

```
<input id="testInput" type="text" value="20" />
```

Check your updated [jsfiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/7h604exp/2/)

Hope it helps,

Comment: Interesting solution, but if I would type (for example 50), I type before 5 and after I delete 2.

Comment: @gatfil right... but the problem is not my solution (which in fact it is simply the explanation from its own documentation on how to deal with this case).Then in my point of view the problem is how `autonumeric` plugin works in this case. If you want to use this plugin there is no other way (at least now, maybe with future versions).

Comment: @albiffc Yes, I undestand! Thank you for your solution!

Comment: @gatfil you're welcome `:)`. If it solve your problem think about [accept it](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)